# Printing in a pyramid pattern puts each number on a separate line

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, newline

I'm not able to remove the spacing in a `for`-loop as numbers are not coming in the same for making the pattern.

My code:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,i):
       print(j)
```

Produces the following result:

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
```

But my desired output is:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
print(j, end='')
```

`end` by default is `\n` (see [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)). Also, be sure to print a newline at the end of each outer loop iteration:

```
for i in range(1,6):  # notice that I changed this to 6
    for j in range(1,i):
        print(j, end='')  # added end=''
    print()  # printing newline here
```

```
1
12
123
1234
```

---

**EDIT** I just noticed you were using Python 2.7. Since that's the case, you can use `print j,` instead of `print(j, end='')` and `print` instead of `print()`. Note that `print j,` will leave spaces between the `j`s. If you don't want this, you can `import sys` and use `sys.stdout.write(j)` instead (see [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)).

Furthermore, if you want to use the Python 3 print function as shown above, you can always

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Won't `print j,` put spaces between the numbers? EG `1 2 3 4` instead of `1234`.

Comment: @mr2ert Yes it will. I explained what to do if the OP doesn't want those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution, if you're interested:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,j)]) for j in range(2,6)]))

1
12
123
1234
```

Comment: When we are printing it its printing successfully. But when we try to assign to a variable inside a function and try to print the variable by calling the function it getting as below.

'1\n1 2\n1 2 3\n1 2 3 4'

why it is so? can u help?

Answer (score 1):

```
for r in range(1,5):
    for c in range (1,r+1):
        print c,
    print
```

here, the print without argument causes printing in the next line

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all of the numbers on one line, you'll have to use one print statement per line you want.  One way you could do this is:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(''.join([str(n) for i in range(1, i)]))
```

Keeping the nested `for` loops you could do:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    temp = ''
    for j in range(1, i):
        temp += str(j)
    print(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks! But watch out the typo in the first code chunk; it's "str(i)" and not "str(n)"

Answer (score 0):

```
def pentagon(num):

    j = num
    for i in range(0, num + 1):
        print('{}{}'.format(' ' * j, ' *' * i))
        j -= 1

pentagon(2)
```

output

```
 *  
* *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def RTN():
    x = 1
    num = int(input('Type any integer besides 0: '))
    if num == 0:
        return 'Try again!'
    while x < num + 2:
        print('')
        for y in range(1, x):
            print(str(y) + ' ', end = '')
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input())

for i in range (1,num+1):
    for j in range(i):
        print(j+1,end = '')
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the idea of @Shiva was really nice and made a slightly more general pyramid function, maybe someone can use/enjoy it it:

```py
def pyramid(n_rows, s, upside_down=False, offset=0):
    whites = ' ' * len(s)
    offset = ' ' * offset

    indices = np.arange(n_rows)

    if upside_down:
        indices = zip(indices[::-1]+1, indices)
    else:
        indices = zip(indices+1, indices[::-1])

    for i, j  in indices:
        print(f"{offset + whites * j}{(s + whites) * i}")


pyramid(4, 'SO')
#       SO  
#     SO  SO  
#   SO  SO  SO  
# SO  SO  SO  SO  

pyramid(4, '*', upside_down=True, offset=3)
#    * * * * 
#     * * * 
#      * * 
#       *
```

Answer (score -3):

x=input('enter some numerical value')

s=''

for i in range(0,x):

```
     for j in range(0,i+1):

              s=s+str(j+1)
     print s
     s=''
```